# $\inf$ of a sequence of $\sup$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, limsup-and-liminf

let $f_n$ a sequence of right-continuous functions $[0,\infty) \to R$. Assume that 
for each $T$:
\begin{align}
& \sup_{\substack{t \in [0,T]\\n \in N}} |f_n(t)|<\infty
\end{align}

Is it true that for each $T$:
\begin{align}
& \inf_{a>0} \sup_{\substack{t \in [0,T+a]\\n \in N}} |f_n(t)|=\sup_{\substack{t \in [0,T]\\n \in N}} |f_n(t)|
\end{align}

My problem is that the $f_n$ need not be equi right-continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be continuous, equal $0$ on $[0,1]$, equal to $1$ on $[1+1/n,\infty)$
and affin-linear on $[1,1+1/n]$. For $T=1$ and every $a>0$ you then have
$$\sup_{t\in [0,1+a],n\in\mathbb N} |f_n(t)| =1 \text{ and } \sup_{t\in [0,1],n\in\mathbb N} |f_n(t)| =0.$$